# Trouble with gcloud installation on Mac

Tags: python, macos, google-cloud-platform, terminal, gcloud

**Note:** I am new to MacOS and its command line. I have multiple python installations.But the main one is through the Anaconda distribution. I have never faced issues with it.

If I activate conda base environment, my python lies in —
`/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`. If conda is deactivated, my other python lies in —
`/usr/bin/python`
I don’t think the issue is here.

**Issue:** I’m trying to run a script on python that generates a csv link and uploads to cloud storage and it did succeed. The storage.googleapis.com did get generated. But, sometimes the code doesn't run completely. I am not sure why this error occurs sometimes. Example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
```

............

I reinstall gcloud sdk and then run it. It works, but not all the time. And when it doesn’t, I have to reinstall.

Also, I do not know why my
`$ gcloud init`
path is not changing, I have tried to change it, but no luck. It always says gcloud command not found. I always have to type
`./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init`
to initialise gcloud sdk.

Comment: can you follow the steps mentioned in the link : https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart#mac still problem persist?